# Python: sorting an array with NaNs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

Note: I'm using Python and numpy arrays.

I have many arrays which all have two columns and many rows.  There are some NaN values in the second column; the first column only has numbers.

I would like to sort each array in increasing order according to the second column, leaving the NaN values out.  It's a big dataset so I would rather not have to convert the NaN values into zeros or something.

I'd like it to sort like so:

```
105.  4.
22.   10.
104.  26.
...
...
...
53.   520.
745.  902.
184.  nan
19.   nan
```

First I tried using `fix_invalid` which converts the NaNs into `1x10^20`:

```
#data.txt has one of the arrays with 2 columns and a bunch of rows.
Data_0_30 = array(genfromtxt(fname='data.txt'))

g = open("iblah.txt", "a") #saves to file

def Sorted_i_M_W(mass):
    masked = ma.fix_invalid(mass)
    print  >> g, array(sorted(masked, key=itemgetter(1)))

Sorted_i_M_W(Data_0_30)

g.close()
```

Or I replaced the function with something like this:

```
def Sorted_i_M_W(mass):
    sortedmass = sorted( mass, key=itemgetter(1))
    print  >> g, array(sortedmass)
```

For each attempt I got something like:

```
...
[  4.46800000e+03   1.61472200e+11]
[  3.72700000e+03   1.74166300e+11]
[  4.91800000e+03   1.75502300e+11]
[  6.43500000e+03              nan]
[  3.95520000e+04   8.38907500e+09]
[  3.63750000e+04   1.27625700e+10]
[  2.08810000e+04   1.28578500e+10]
...
```

Where at the location of the NaN value, the sorting re-starts again.

(For the `fix_invalid` the NaN in the above excerpt shows a `1.00000000e+20` value). But I'd like the sorting to ignore the NaN value completely.

What's the easiest way to sort this array the way I want?

Comment: Have you tried using a `filter()` call to remove elements with `nan` before sorting the remainder of the list?

Comment: Why are you sorting in python instead of using numpy?

Comment: In the latest version of numpy, the function sort can deal with nans in the way you are seeking. Here is the link http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: Why not something like: `key=lambda x: x[1] if x[1] == x[1] else float('+inf')` to put the NaNs at the end? I believe this wont be *that* much slower in the end. However if you can, just use `numpy` functions that will be *much* faster.

Comment: Building on @freude's comment, you can see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npysort/npysort_common.h#L120) how the C function doing comparisons for floats handles this, which works because `np.nan != np.nan` evaluates to `True`, while any other comparison involving `np.nan` returns `False`.

Comment: You say "I tried using `fix_invalid`" but you never showed where it came from. I presume you mean [`numpy.ma.fix_invalid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.fix_invalid.html). Please make sure to add the missing imports or explanation to make this an MRE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done with `numpy.sort`, but you can use `numpy.argsort` for sure:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 105.,    4.],
       [  53.,  520.],
       [ 745.,  902.],
       [  19.,   nan],
       [ 184.,   nan],
       [  22.,   10.],
       [ 104.,   26.]])
>>> arr[np.argsort(arr[:,1])]
array([[ 105.,    4.],
       [  22.,   10.],
       [ 104.,   26.],
       [  53.,  520.],
       [ 745.,  902.],
       [  19.,   nan],
       [ 184.,   nan]])
```

Comment: another problem worth noticing is that np.argsort can not sort a object array with np.nan in it.
if a array is dtype == object, the np.nan will not be placed correctly (and there is no warning)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a masked array:

```
a = np.loadtxt('test.txt')

mask = np.isnan(a)
ma = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=mask)
```

And then sort `a` using the masked array:

```
a[np.argsort(ma[:, 1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use comparision function

```
def cmpnan(x, y):
    if isnan(x[1]):
        return 1 # x is "larger"
    elif isnan(y[1]):
        return -1 # x is "smaller"
    else:
        cmp(x[1], y[1]) # compare numbers

sorted(data, cmp=cmpnan)
```

see http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an older version of numpy and don't want to upgrade (or if you want code that supports older versions of numpy) you can do:

```
import numpy as np

def nan_argsort(a):
    temp = a.copy()
    temp[np.isnan(a)] = np.inf
    return temp.argsort()

sorted = a[nan_argsort(a[:, 1])]
```

In newer versions of numpy, at least 1.6 I think, numpy's sort/argsort already has this behavior. If you need to use python's sort for some reason, you can make your own compare function as described in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

if you really don't want to use numpy array, you could sort the second column, then get the index to call you array.

it can be done in one line only like this:

```
yourarray[sorted(range(len(yourarray[:,1])), key=lambda k: yourarray[:,1][k])]
```